# Javascript - Replacing multiple parts of string in one go

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace multiple parts of a string with different things. I have a series of URLs that contain these strings that need to change, they all follow the same pattern.

e.g.

- 'spanish-beginners-course'
- 'italian-beginners-course'
- 'spanish-italian-beginners-course'

I just want the result to be the languages e.g. spanish, italian, spanish italian

I have tried this as a test but it returns 'spanish undefined undefined'

```
const pageName = 'spanish-beginners-course'
const chars = { '-beginners': '', '-course': '', '-': ' ' }
const language = pageName.replace(/-|beginners|course/g, m => chars[m])
```

Comment: Do you need regex? Can you just use e.g. `'spanish-beginners-course'.replace('-beginners-course','')`?

Comment: it needs to cover multiple languages like 'spanish-italian-beginners-course' too

Comment: Well it would, just do `pageName.replace('-beginners-course','')`

Comment: Or if you need the space instead of the hyphen use `pageName.replace('-beginners-course','').replace('-', ' ')`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your REGEX match finds `beginners`, but in your `chars` object there is no key called `beginners` - it's called `-beginners`. Same for `course`/`-course`.

```
const pageName = 'spanish-beginners-course'
const chars = { '-beginners': '', '-course': '', '-': ' ' }
const language = pageName.replace(/-|beginners|course/g, m => chars[m])
```

In any case your object is unnecessary, and so is REGEX (as @Alastair points out) since you're replacing a static, unchanging substring.

```
const language = pageName.replace('-beginners-course', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is very simple, you can split and take first.

```js
let pageName = "spanish-beginners-course";
let language = pageName.split(/-/)[0];
console.log(language); // spanish
pageName = "italian-beginners-course";
language = pageName.split(/-/)[0];
console.log(language); //italian
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get null because this part `-|beginners|course` is an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) which will match either `-`, `beginners` or `course`

You use the match to get the value from the object, but the object contains `-beginners` and `-course`

If you want to do the replacement, and there has to be at least 1 word before it, you could use a capturing group `$1` in the replacement and match after it what you want to remove.

```
(\w+(?:-\w+)*)-beginners-course\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lFVzhi/1)

```js
const pageName = 'spanish-beginners-course';
const language = pageName.replace(/(\w+(?:-\w+)*)-beginners-course\b/g, "$1");
console.log(language)
```

```js
[
  'spanish-beginners-course',
  'italian-beginners-course',
  'spanish-italian-beginners-course',
  'donotremove!-beginners-course'
]
.forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/(\w+(?:-\w+)*)-beginners-course\b/g, "$1")));
```